# How to get log filename in codec plugin inside of file input plugin logstash

Tags: logstash

The below is the code that I want to ask.

```
input {
    file {
            path => "directory/*.log"
            start_position => "beginning"
            codec => my_own_codec_plugin {
                ....
            }
            sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}
```

I have some log files in same directory. I can reach out them with using * in path. I have created "**my_own_codec_plugin**" for file input plugin.

I want to pass the log filename to "**my_own_codec_plugin**".

I mean if path reaches the logfile1.log send the name to codec plugin, then it reaches logfile2.log send the filename to the codec plugin again.

How can i do this ? Thanks for answering

Comment: The codec cannot reference the name of the file that the file input is currently processing. You could pass a path option to your codec but if the glob returns multiple files you cannot keep the codec and input in sync.

Comment: You mean giving path option to my codec by manual writing to name of file ?

Comment: I am saying you could do: file { path => "/path/filename.log" codec => my_own_codec_plugin { path => "/path/filename.log" } }. It will not work with wildcards.

Comment: I know this. Thank you but my question about making this automatically. path => "../*.log" codec { path => [path]} sth like that

Comment: As I said in my first comment, that is not possible.

Comment: In your custom codec, you're receiving the event and the event should have a `path` field with the actual path of the file, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you re right @Val

Answer (score 1):

In your custom codec, you're receiving the event and the event should have a `path` field with the actual path of the file that you can use.

Comment: You mean "message" field has to have the path (inside in log line has to have path). Otherwise I can not get, which log file is reading by file plugin In input {}  ?

Comment: No, what I meant is that the file input plugin automatically adds to the event a new field called `path` that contains the path of the file and that you should be able to use inside your codec logic.

Comment: Yes, but i can reach that path field in filter. How can reach that field  at inside of codec plugin ?

Comment: Inside your codec plugin logic, if you print out all fields of an event, what do you get?

Comment: I m reaching data with below code                                                                   
config :charset, :validate => ::Encoding.name_list, :default => "UTF-8"              
converter = LogStash::Util::Charset.new(charset)
message = converter.convert(data).strip
yield LogStash::Event.new(MESSAGE_FIELD => message)  if !message.nil?

Comment: With that code, I can only reach log line and modify, then yield event

Comment: Could you give an example ? How to reach this field in codec ?